# Bevel operation results in different result in similar mesh

Tags: edit-mode, bevel

I have 2 house shaped objects that are made following different sequences of extrude, knife, and edge dissolve. Now when I try to bevel the top edge of the house I get two different results. How do I start investigating what the problems/difference is in my model? (The back one is what I expected)

[image]

A file showcasing the problem has been recreated here: (Not uploaded by OP)

[image]

Comment: Looks as if you may have a disconnected or duplicate edge on the front one. In vertex mode, select all then press 'm' and Merge by Distance and see if any vertices are removed on the bottom status bar. Then try again. If that doesn't do it, upload your blend file so that we can have a look.

Comment: Yes, I merged vertices but the problem still persists. I forgot to save the file, but I'll attach it here if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: no you didn't merge them. If you had merged them, the problem would have been gone. i just tried it. in your uploaded file are still duplicate vertices.

Comment: @Chris Please note that the file was not upload by me. It was uploaded by Allen Simpson.

Comment: Yes and I must be crazy because last night I swear I had one with no extra vertices.  Oh well, I will post my answer anyway when I get home

Comment: Hello Quazi, this question popped up yesterday and it reminded me of this.  I think you stumbled onto a situation which produces this odd behavior.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/229916/110840

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly how it happened - I'm sure there are a million ways to achieve it, but the only way I've found to reproduce this is to scale a face to 0.

So, ignoring the issue of vertices for the moment.  There is a single edge at the top of the house in the back, it bevels correctly.  On the front house, you're selecting one edge of the two edges that exist in the same place at the top of the house.

If you weren't aware that it was created, it's not clear that it even exists or is available for selection *if you're not in x-ray view*.  It is also beveling "correctly" it's just that the nearest edge is in the same position so you just see it crawling down the roof.

[image]

Moving the edges around (right click sends it back to its original location) you can spot the problem easily, and in x-ray view you can select the edge again to grab what is under it - the second edge.

[image]

It's also possible that a Merge would not work for a similar reason.  If you tried to box select all the verts and you weren't in x-ray view, you probably wouldn't catch any vertices that were hidden beneath others.

[image]

If you want to get the whole mesh, box select while in x-ray view or press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all.

[image]